# Parse c-clang index.h file with with clang itself

Tags: clang

I am trying to parse c-clang index.h file with ClangSharp (just for testing purposes of ClangSharp parser on C#) and I found that it misses parsing of functions because of `CINDEX_LINKAGE` macro in the function declaration.

If I remove it, parser will correctly find FunctionDecl and parse it without errors.

I cannot understand how this macro preventing functions from being parsed. Does someone know how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in the `#include` line itself. By default, clang header includes setup to search in the directory on one level up, but clang itself by some reason does not understand such 
include format.